# Connect to another AWS account in Visual Studio Team Explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2017, aws-toolkit

I installed AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2017. I clicked "Connect" and provided all the necessary keys. It got connected to my office AWS account.

Now I have a free account of AWS for learning purpose. I have a sample repository in CodeCommit under free account. Now I want to connect to this account.

Whenever I click "Connect", it automatically connects to office account and not offering me to enter credentials of the free account.

I opened "Manage Connections", but there I can only add a new Microsoft account not AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your free account as a profile. The [Providing AWS Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/credentials.html) guide will walk you through adding multiple AWS profiles. Then, when you click "Connect" a pop up will allow you to choose the AWS profile that you would like for the connection. Once connected, there is an option to sign out if you would like to connect with a different profile.